# Simulator won't work after re-installing xcode

Tags: xcode, rubymotion

I am working with ruby motion.
As I had an issue when the app within the simulator did not want to scroll I re-installed xcode.
The problem seemed to be resolved. Everything worked fine.
However, suddenly the simulator would not open anymore with any app, providing different reasons.

So I deleted the application xcode again and re-installed it. (version 7.3(7D175)

I ran „bundle“ as well as rake pod:install and then rake.

The simulator would not open.

Reasons given in crashlog:

App 1 (this is the one which had worked before in the simulator):

"app was built for iOS 9.2 which is newer than this simulator 9.0"

```
Process:               Lactase 2 [17362]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91C530C5-CE00-457A-9DBD-EA95ABF0FBB0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F5FEF342-5AD5-4B3D-9940-24D9D2DEAFA5/Lactase 2.app/Lactase 2
Identifier:            Lactase 2
Version:               1.0.7 (1.0.7)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [17303]
Responsible:           Lactase 2 [17362]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-03-17 11:50:56.139 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3 (15D21)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        2349157F-CC76-5FE5-556C-A99898CF9E77

Sleep/Wake UUID:       A44189DB-1F86-45D8-8A53-AF8F93C8BCCA

Time Awake Since Boot: 75000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_SHARED_REGION=avoid

Dyld Error Message:
  app was built for iOS 9.2 which is newer than this simulator 9.0

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x946ff7 +com.nikolajandersen.lactase2 (1.0.7 - 1.0.7) <3043889D-4115-3C92-9664-BB59B91D04DF> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/91C530C5-CE00-457A-9DBD-EA95ABF0FBB0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F5FEF342-5AD5-4B3D-9940-24D9D2DEAFA5/Lactase 2.app/Lactase 2
  0xecb000 -   0xeee377 +dyld_sim (360.19) <1A1E6A99-E860-37B8-BCEE-4B0A54ECCA01> /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 9.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
0x8fe52000 - 0x8fe8658f  dyld (360.19) <8F9518A3-884D-35FF-8FD9-FB149B7F1BF2> /usr/lib/dyld
```

I checked: The Simulator is Version 9.3 (SimulatorApp-645.9

App 2 (a different app which had also worked before in the simulator)

The reason provided for crashing is strange: It refers to a faulty code in the app. However, I had commented it out.

I would have included the entire report but I am not allowed more than 30.000 characters. So this is [a link](http://www.bestideasfuture.com/?p=1637) to the report.

What could be the reason for the problem?
Should I delete not only the application xcode but also other files when re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

**First try:** Did you also tried to install a 9.2 simulator on Xcode and ran your code ? Maybe it isn't up- or downgrade-able.

**Second try:** did you try to set up a new app on 9.3 and copy and paste your code into your new app ?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

No, I did not install a 9.2 simulator consciously.

1. I ran "rake clean:all"
No change.

2. Window > Devices: I deleted one item

3. I specified in Rakefile (before it had been on default)
no change

4. There were just two runtimes installed (9.1 and 9.2). No 9.3
I deleted the two.

And this is the crash report now: link [link](http://www.bestideasfuture.com/?p=1640)

Comment: @danielo007 did you modified this SDK file ? It seems to be broken anyways: "‚/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk/usr/include/sysexits.h‘
has been modified since the precompiled header"

Comment: No, I did not modify it (as far as I know).

However: THIS issue has been resolved just now after I deleted the 'Module Cache'

Comment: following this path:
'rm -rf '/var/folders/97/htb_nnqs25j1yskj8pj21d0m0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.danielo/ModuleCache''

The simulator opens now.
However, the original problem is still there: I cannot scroll until the end within an app which contains a list. This is true for any app.

Comment: That issue had been the reason why I had deleted x-code in the first place hoping that the problem would be gone after re-installing it. But instead the simulator would crash every time.

Do you have a clue what I could do about this problem?